# Not able to change svg color , fill and stroke

Tags: css, svg, colors, mixins, fill

I want to make my SVG completely white, but can't seem to manage to do so

https://jsfiddle.net/0Lpewkc1/1/

For some reason is the black color stuck?
But why?

```css
@mixin test( $setSize: $size, $Fill: $Fill, $Stroke: $Stroke, ) {
  height: $setSize;
  width: $setSize;
  & use,
  & svg {
    stroke: $Stroke;
    fill: $Fill;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}

.play {
  test(rem(45), white, white)
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="play">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="100%" height="100%">
      <path d="M106.667 81.467v48L360.533 256l-211.2 11s.133v-236.8l-42.666-23.466v330.666s
450.133 256 106.667 71.467z" fill="#192228"></path></svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

From the browser

```
play {
    height: 2.875rem;
    width: 2.875rem;
}

.play use, .play svg {
    stroke: #fff;
    fill: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! When I try compiling your SCSS to CSS using an online tool, it says there's a syntax error. I'm unfamiliar with SCSS, so I can't tell what's actually wrong. I think jsFiddle might be skipping the CSS, and hiding the error.

Comment: BTW, if you can compile your SCSS to CSS and include it in the "snippet" I added above, that might help others look at your issue, even if they're unfamiliar with Sass.

Comment: I am not sure what I else I can do than a fiddle post,  any recomme nations?

Comment: Looks like you need to target the `fill` of the `svg path` not just the `svg`. The path has `fill="#192228"` set

Comment: @Loser As far as compiling SCSS, you can use a tool [like this](http://beautifytools.com/scss-compiler.php), which give error messages. Or, you could manually write out the CSS that you want, instead of using SCSS. But, if zgood's suggestion works, then this is a tip for next time. :-)

Comment: The actual SVG is part of an `#shadowpage` so I don't think i can change it..

Comment: @zgood I am not sure I understand..

Comment: @loser see my answer and updated fiddle

Comment: added the css, not sure how to include in snippet

Answer (score 2):

You need to target the `svg path` since thats what you want change the fill of.

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7b1jk4vu/)

```
@mixin test( $setSize: $size, $Fill: $Fill, $Stroke: $Stroke, ) {
  height: $setSize;
  width: $setSize;
  & use,
  & svg path { // <-- Update this
    stroke: $Stroke;
    fill: $Fill;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}

.play {
  @include test(rem(45), red, white)
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="play">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="100%" height="100%"><path d="M106.667 81.467v48L360.533 256l-211.2 11s.133v-236.8l-42.666-23.466v330.666s
450.133 256 106.667 71.467z" fill="#192228"></path></svg>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm... What I pasted in there is the actual shadow page.. Would it also work outside..

Comment: I have no idea what a "shadow page" is sorry. It does work in the fiddle though so I have hopes ;)